# QAM and APSK error comparision

Tags: modulation, demodulation

Due to the 16QAM and 16APSK characteristic, is there exact comparison between 16QAM and 16APSK BER?

Comment: Why shouldn't there be? It's a bit unclear why you're asking this. BER is defined independent of the modulation scheme, so it's *always* possible to compare modulation schemes w.r.t. their BER under identical conditions (e.g. AWGN SNR).